# Validate certifier id file against password on user registration in domino server using c#

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

I am registering a new user on a domino server using certifier id file and password option using c# program. I am getting certifier id file and password as an input form user interface. If I am providing wrong password for id file, during the user registration process a window is popped up for asking password again. Is it possible to verify the password against certifier id file programmatic way? So that I can alert the user before start registering user. Are is there any way to suppress the password window popup and catch the exception ?.

Comment: Simply: don't do it that way. Automating a process that passes around ids and their passwords is very bad practice. Just enable Certificate Authority and you need NEITHER ID NOR Password, just a user that is allowed to register other users with that ID in the CA store...

Answer (score 0):

The Notes core is pretty strict about bypassing normal logic for passwords, for very good reasons I might add. The only way of suppressing the password popup, which I'm not even sure will work for a cert id password, would be with a custom DLL written using the Notes C API's Extension Manager feature. That would require deploying the DLL to the PC of every user who is doing the registrations. There is probably not a way, even using the C API, to validate the password before registering and without triggering the popup, but I'm not sure of that.

Comment: I have tried using Extension Manager Feature for EM_GETPASSWORD but it seems the popup is not suppressed.